# Benefit of assigning a variable via eval in php?

Tags: php, eval

Good day!
Currently i'm studying a class  which has a following line:

```
if( $something) {  eval ('$actualValue = &$this->'.$value.';'); }
```

Could you explain to me pro & cons of using eval and writing it without eval 
(just assign a value via a php regularly )

**UPDATE 1**

Sorry for this, but i just saw in the other part of the class a more complete version of using eval:

```
if( $something) {  
eval ('$actualValue = &$this->'.$value.';'); 
if(isset($actualValue)) { 
//some code
}
}
```

It's clearer now... but still there's a question : why not do it without  eval... just don't get it.
But still thanks everyone for your answers & giving links!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about eval in PHP 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482861/question-about-eval-in-php-5)

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) on more information how and when to use eval, really good thread

Comment: Jack, I don't think this is the same question at all. They are both about eval, but the similarities ends there.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no benefit to this. This is much better:

```
$actualValue = &$this->$value;
```

I think someone didn't know you could do this and so they reinvented the wheel.

Comment: And fast, so no consuming time for eval function.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following question I asked:

[Dynamically Populating Multi-Dimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919096/dynamically-populating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

I used eval to create a dynamic multidimensional array based on parameters tossed via a function argument.

But, it is much easier to just store variables via reference.